# How to create an activation key in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create an activation key that if entered correctly, will carry on the python script, if entered incorrectly, it'll send the whole thing and have to rerun it all. This is what i've got so far:

```
activeKey = "ILoveCoding45"

enterActiveKey = input("Please enter the activation key down below:\n")
if activeKey == enterActiveKey:
    print("Activation key is successful.")
while activeKey != enterActiveKey:
    print("Activation key is incorrect. Please re-run the program")
    break
```

And either when it's entered correctly, the python script will keep running like normal, and i don't want that. Any bits of help would be great, thanks

Comment: `sys.exit(1)` instead of the `break`

Comment: Do you want to keep prompting for the activation key? You have a `while` which suggests you do, and an error message which suggests you don't.

Comment: Does rerun mean go back to prompt for input?

Answer (score 0):

```
activeKey = "ILoveCoding45"

while True:
    enterActiveKey = input("Please enter the activation key down below:\n")
    if activeKey == enterActiveKey:
        break
    print("Activation key is incorrect.")

print("Activation key is successful.")
code after success
```